# java pointers and state machine

Tags: java, garbage-collection, state-machine

My question is more about error prevention than it is about getting something to work. Making a fsm, changing the state pointer inside a state, what exactly happens. Let me post some code to make my question more clear. I will try to keep the bare minimum to get my point across:

```
class foo{
    abstract fsm {
        abstract void enter();
        final void changeState(fsm state) { State = state; State.enter() }
    }

    state1 extends fsm ... implementation left out
    state2 extends fsm...  implementation left out

    fsm State = null;

    foo(){
         State = new state1;
         State.changeState(new state2);
     }
}
```

So my question is, when changeState occurs, State is set to a new State, and then its enter() method is called. But what happens to the current state, that is the currentState.changeState(...) meaning that we are still in a previous state's method's call. Does that method remain on the stack until it goes through all of its code and returns (that is there are two states in memory - the previous state(because of its method call still executing) and the new state and its enter method call executing.) or those the previous state become flagged for garbage collection since there is no pointer pointing to it anymore, and it is possible (unlikely, but possible) that the method may be garbage collected before the method can finish executing?

Like I said, this question is more deep and involved and is about how the JVM works, and garbage collection / pointer execution. All replies are welcomed, but I would like links to articles on this if possible. Thank you all

Comment: Conceptually speaking, this is probably not how I'd go about implementing a FSM at all...I admit, I'm very perplexed by this question.  What exactly are you asking here?  Are you asking about what would happen if your `changeState` call were invoked as-is (assuming it was valid, which it really isn't)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So my question is, when changeState occurs, State is set to a new State, and then its enter() method is called. But what happens to the current state, that is the currentState.changeState(...) meaning that we are still in a previous state's method's call. Does that method remain on the stack until it goes through all of its code and returns (that is there are two states in memory - the previous state(because of its method call still executing) and the new state and its enter method call executing.)

Correct.

> or those the previous state become flagged for garbage collection since there is no pointer pointing to it anymore

It is still executing so it cannot be garbage-collected.

> and it is possible (unlikely, but possible) that the method may be garbage collected before the method can finish executing?

No. Methods are not gargabe-collected.

This is not a correct way to implement an FSM in Java. For one thing if there are enough transitions you will get a `StackOverflowError`. There should be a loop that keeps calling `enter()` on the next state until it is a 'finished' state, and there should be a `setNextState()` method that is called at the end of each `enter()` method to determine what should happen next. The current state should not itself call that new state's `enter()` method.

Comment: Thank you. I didn't quite implement mine this way, although not much different. Mine, I just had the new state, and instead of an enter() method I had a constructor for the state. Maybe not the best way to implement it, but since android doesn't seem to really make use of a loop, it made it harder to properly call the next states setup. I'm using a state machine for my views, to choose which view to display. I preferred it over having many different classes just to display a simple list, or menu, etc.. the state chooses what to show (also better than a messy if then else nest. Thank you again

Comment: The current state should not itself call the contructor of the new state either, for the same reason.

Comment: Actually, an object can be eligible for GC while a method in that object is still executing as long as the slot for the `this` pointer is never used again by the method's bytecode. See [When does an object become eligible for garbage collection?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2010/08/10/10048149.aspx) (which is about C#, but most JVMs are similar) for details.